# Complete account before logging in (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In the site I am developing, some users are able to sign-up for an account, but leave the registration process part-way through.

However, if they have passed a critical stage in registration, they will be allowed to log in if they try. At this point, I want to direct them to a page where they must complete their account details before they are able to access the site.

I am looking to make a sort of impenetrable wall, so they must complete registration before using their account. Currently, I am just redirecting the users once they login, like this:

```
public function authenticated($request, $user)
{
    if ($user->regComplete == false) {
        auth()->logout();
        flash('you are not verified');
        return redirect('/login');
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

However, I would like to redirect some users to the aforementioned page. I will redirect them like this

```
if ($user->incomplete) {
    return redirect('/account/complete');
}
```

However, I am not too sure what the best practice is for a compulsory account completion page is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use **Middlewares** for such use cases. :)

```
php artisan make:middleware UserProfileComplete
```

Then replace the `handle` function with this :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {
  // Please note here complete = 1 means user has completed his profile 
  if(!auth()->user()->complete) { 
    return redirect(route('user.account.complete'));
  }

  return $next($request);
}
```

Then go to your `App\Http\Kernel.php` and add this to `$routeMiddleware`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
  'user.profile' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserProfileComplete::class,
];
```

Finally, in you `routes.php` you can do

```
Route::group('account', ['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {

  Route::get('complete', 'UserController@completeProfile')->name('user.account.complete');

});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'user.profile']], function() {

  //Routes which needs to check if profile is complete or not

});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Great answer. Except, this wouldn't work, because the `complete` Route will never be reached, due to the middleware, which is not matched. This will end in a infinite loop. The right way would be, to set this complete Route just in an `auth` group, and the other account routes inside the above middleware group. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @JanWillem Completely agree on it. Fixed now... Thanks :)

Comment: @prateekkathal . I did this method, but this method works for both cases where the user has completed his profile or not. I need to say that the user profile table and the login table are separate. Please explain how the `complete` method works?